# Utilizar la variable de otra Sub VBA

Tags: vba

Tengo un problema al querer utilizar la variable "nombre" de otra subrutina. Ésta la quiero para poder editar una gráfica. En este caso la primera subrutina genera la gráfica y le pone el nombre. En la segunda subrutina, la quiero editar pero no puedo llamar la variable "nombre" que es donde tengo cómo se llama la gráfica.

```
Public **nombre** As String

Sub GRAFICA2()

Dim Grafica As String
    nombre = InputBox("Escribe el nombre de la grafica:")       

Dim Rango As Range
    Set Rango = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Rango
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = nombre

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(nombre).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Delete

Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(nombre).Chart

    cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
    cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
    cht.ChartArea.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End Sub

Sub grafica2A()

Dim Rango2 As Range
    Set Rango2 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(nombre).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Rango2

End Sub
```

Comment: Me equivoque en esta parte:

Dim Grafica As String
Grafica = InputBox("Escribe el nombre de la grafica:")
nombre = 5

Realmente lo tengo asi

nombre = InputBox("Escribe el nombre de la grafica:")

Comment: por favor, no incluyas correcciones a tu pregunta en los comentarios. Edita tu pregunta y haz la corrección directamente

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas utilizar una variable fuera de un método, ¿Por qué no definirla fuera de este?

Ejemplo:

```
Dim Numero As Integer

Sub AumentarN()
    Numero = Numero + 1
    MsgBox Numero
End Sub

Sub ProcPrincipal()
    Numero = 5
    MsgBox Numero
    AumentarN ' Llamamos a la subrutina.
End Sub
```

Resultado de `ProcPrincipal()`:

```
5
6
```

Lo que aplicado a tu caso sería:

```
Dim NombreGrafica As String
Sub GRAFICA2()
    ' ...
    NombreGrafica = InputBox("Escribe el nombre de la grafica:")
    ' ...
End Sub

Sub grafica2A()
    Dim Rango2 As Range
    Set Rango2 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(NombreGrafica).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Rango2
End Sub
```

O bien, puedes hacer lo que se ha recomendado en la respuesta de [Javier Solis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15521/4499)

Answer (score 0):

Cada subrutina solo tiene acceso a las variables que se declararon dentro de ella, si quieres obtener nombre deberias pasarlo como parametro a tu funcion

```
Sub grafica2A(nombre)

   Dim Rango2 As Range Set Rango2 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(nombre).Activate
   ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
   ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Rango2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega otra subrutina, que sirva para hacer 3 cosas:
1) pedir el nombre de la gráfica.
2) ejecutar gráfica2 con el nombre como parámetro.
3) ejecutar gráfica2A con el nombre como parámetro.

```
Sub ejecutar()
nombre=inputbox("Escriba un supernombre sorprendente de supergráfica: ")
grafica2(nombre)
grafica2A(nombre)
End Sub

Sub grafica2(Optional ByVal unNombre as String = "Grafiquita2")
.......
End Sub

Sub grafica2A(Optional ByVal unNombre as String = "Grafiquita2A")
.......
End Sub
```